# Accordion Issue

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am setting up this site at games.nyls.edu.  If you see when you click on any of the links on the 2nd column it opens up the first link.  heres the code:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=computable-diagrams&showposts=10'); ?>
<?php echo '<a onclick="changeCssClass(\'widget-title3\')" id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle3(\'wp-cpl-widget3\', \'imageDivLink\');"><h3 id="widget-title3" class="widget-title">Computable Diagrams</h3></a> <ul id="wp-cpl-widget3" class="wp-cpl-widget" style="display: none;">'; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <li class="wp-cpl wp-cpl-even"><a href="javascript:toggle9('testcontent3', 'imageDivLink6');">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>  </li><div id="testcontent3" style="display:none;"><?php the_content();?></div> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Post the outputted HTML, that would probably explain things.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="testcontent3" style="display:none;">
```

this is inside loop ... will produce duplicate ids on the page ...you need to have unique id's for divs

Comment: so should I keep it in the loop and just make a parameter i.e. count?  thanks for the quick assistance